Formula including divisors sum ($\sigma$), Euler Gamma ($\gamma$), $\pi$ and $\ln \pi$
An interesting formula arose during the investigation of divisors sum efficient calculation. Actually the below series converges very slowly, as every series containing $\gamma$ :)
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sigma (k)}{k}\left(\frac{1+ 2 \pi ^{3/2} \sqrt{2 k}}{e^{2 \pi ^{3/2} \sqrt{2 k}}}-\frac{\pi ^{3/2}}{(2 k+\pi )^{3/2}}\right)=\frac{\gamma }{2}-\frac{\pi ^3}{6}+\frac{1}{8 \pi }-1+\log (2 \pi )$$
Would like to highlight this not very trivial formula and ask if someone saw similar formulas, or articles about similar relations?
This formula ispired by the Divisors Sum Related Interesting Approximate Relation.
Also there are other formulas, that make me think that others also investigated this kind of sums:
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sigma (k)}{k}\left(\frac{4 \sqrt{\pi  k}+1}{e^{4 \sqrt{\pi  k}}}-\frac{1}{(\pi  k+1)^{3/2}}\right) =\frac{\gamma }{2}-\frac{61 \pi }{48}+\log (2)$$
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \frac{\sigma (k)}{k}\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{2 \sqrt{\pi } k}+1}{e^{2 \sqrt{2 \sqrt{\pi } k}}}-\frac{1}{\left(2 \pi ^{3/2} k+1\right)^{3/2}}\right) =\frac{\gamma }{2}+\frac{(3 \pi -4) \sqrt{\pi }}{24} -1+\log (2)-\frac{\log (\pi )}{4}$$
